# How to solve this linear programming problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Basically I have to minimize a linear equation with a bunch of $\leq$ constraints.

I know only how to use simplex method to maximise the equation with the $\leq$ constraints. How can I use the simplex method to do the problem I am faced with?

Is there a way I can relate the two so I can use the simplex method I know to get the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\arg \max f(x) = \arg \min -f(x)$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by arg?

Comment: So if I make the function negative (the function I need to minimize) then solve this using the simplex the whatever the maximum value is I take the negative and then that will be my answer? The point that is a maximum is the same in both cases though right?

Comment: $\arg \min$ is shorthand for the *argument* the *minimizes* the function. Here, the argument is $x$.

Comment: For your second question: Yes, if you want to minimize $f(x)$, you are also maximizing $-f(x)$...they are two ways of saying the same thing. In either case, the solution (read: $x$) will be the same, but the objective function values will have opposite signs.

Comment: Okay think I got it now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can adapt your simplex method for minimization very simply.

The only part that changes is when you choose which variable enters your basis:
instead of choosing the variable with maximum reduced cost, choose the one with minimum reduced cost.

Remember the interpretation of the reduced cost of a variable out of the base: it is a measure of how much your objective function will increase or decrease. Therefore, to minimize it must be as small as possible, to maximize it must be as large as possible. When all reduced costs are positive (negative) you have reached optimality for minimization (maximization).